# reading a specific line of text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, text, line

i have a code to read a text file in javascript

```
<input type="file" id="input" onchange="readFile()">

<script>
function readFile(){
     var fr = new FileReader();
     fr.onload = function() {
       var textContent = fr.result;
       //The code
     }
  
  fr.readAsText(document.getElementById("input").files[0]);
}
</script>
```

but the file that i want to read is too big
so i want to read a specific line of it in javascript

***Important***

**I want it in javascript not node.js**

**The files is local not online**

Comment: You cannot change that on the client. You can use a proxy on the server to scan and extract the parts you want. If the file is on your harddisk, you will need to read the complete file to get at the line

Comment: My comment combined with the correct dupes is answering you question